# measure/count logins & file transfers from csv data

Tags: powershell

I have data that looks like this;

```
username    method      ip         uri-stem
ABC\bob1    RETR    192.45.00.00    file.txt
    -       USER    10.00.00.01     bob2
ABC\bob2    STOR    10.00.00.01     file1234.txt
    -       USER    192.45.00.00    bob1
ABC\bob1    RETR    192.45.00.00    file2.txt
```

& I need it to look like this

```
user        Ip            loginCount  FilesIn   FilesOut
bob1    192.45.00.00          5          3         3
bob2    00.00.00.00           3          2         2
```

```
#Key
RETR = FilesOut
STOR = FilesIn
USER = loginCount
```

This is what I have so far for formatting into the first bit of data

```
$inputFile = ".\u_ex230201.log" 
$inputHeaders = "date","time","c-ip","c-port","cs-username","s-sitename","s-computername","cs-host","s-ip","s-port","cs-method","cs-uri-stem","sc-status","sc-win32-status","sc-substatus","sc-bytes","cs-bytes","time-taken","x-session","x-fullpath","x-debug"
$codes = "USER","RETR","STOR" 

Import-Csv $inputfile -Header $inputHeaders -Delimiter ' '  |  
    ForEach-Object {  
        $code = $_.'cs-method'  
        if ($codes -contains $code){ 
            [PSCustomObject]@{  
                username = $_.'cs-username'
                method   = $_.'cs-method'
                ip       = $_.'c-ip'
                uri-stem = $_.'cs-uri-stem'
                Results  = [int]$_.Results  
            }  
        }  
    } | export-csv .\export
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a pivot table.  Try this

```
$csv = @"
username    method      ip         uri-stem
ABC\bob1    RETR    192.45.00.00    file.txt
    -       USER    10.00.00.01     bob2
ABC\bob2    STOR    10.00.00.01     file1234.txt
    -       USER    192.45.00.00    bob1
ABC\bob1    RETR    192.45.00.00    file2.txt
"@
#remove spaces at beginning of line
$csv = $csv -replace ".* -","-"
#replace spaces with comma
$csv = $csv -replace " +",","
$table = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv


foreach($row in $table)
{
   $row.username = $row.username -replace "^.*\\",""
   if($row.username -eq "-") { $row.username = $row.'uri-stem' }
}
#$table

$groups = $table | Group-Object -Property username
$pivotTable = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($row in @($groups))
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName user -NotePropertyValue $row.Name
   $firstGroup = $row.Group | Select-Object -first 1

   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName IP -NotePropertyValue $firstGroup.IP

   $FilesOut = @($row.Group | Where-Object {$_.method -eq "RETR"})
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FilesOut -NotePropertyValue $FilesOut.Count
   $FilesIn = @($row.Group | Where-Object {$_.method -eq "STOR"})
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FilesIn -NotePropertyValue $FilesIn.Count
   $loginCount = @($row.Group | Where-Object {$_.method -eq "USER"})
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName loginCount -NotePropertyValue $loginCount.Count
   $pivotTable.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$pivotTable  | Format-Table
```

Output

```
user IP           FilesOut FilesIn loginCount
---- --           -------- ------- ----------
bob1 192.45.00.00        2       0          1
bob2 10.00.00.01         0       1          1
```